# What is the best approach to create new tables in existing db with data?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-database-first, ef-model-first

I am about to begin a new project which will target an existing database with some existing tables with data. As part of my project, i will create some new tables and make relation ships with the existing tables ? Which approach is better in this scenario. I believe code first will be a problem because i don't want to loose my data every time when i make a change to the table structure (for my new table).

Answer (score 1):

Model-first would be the easier solution. You would just create a model from the database and then you will update the database from the model after adding new entities.

You can achieve the same result with code-first too, but with a little extra work. You will need to use EF Migrations to add the new tables to your database. You can read more about EF Migrations [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx).